# Uploading a File from Django FileField to Nex.js public folder

Tags: reactjs, django, next.js

Is there a way to upload a file in Django outside of the project directory?

I am trying to upload a file/image from the front-end (Next.js) through a FileField in Django and save it in the public folder of the Next.js project directory as that's where all my images are served from.

In this scenario, Django and Next are sibling folders on the server.

If I try to upload anything above the Django project folder via FileField, I get the error:
`Detected path traversal attempt...`

I can use FileSystemStorage, but this is not supposed to be used in production.

How can I upload a file through Django to a folder outside of the project directory and place it in the Next.js public folder successfully?

Comment: Note that files added to the `public` folder at runtime won't be served by Next.js. See Next.js [Static File Serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving).

Comment: So to be able to upload at runtime, am I only able to do this via a CDN? What other simpler option might there be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that since the public folder is not able to be used dynamically, the best case here is to serve the files/images from either a CDN or simply from the Django media folder.

As far as I can tell, there is no discernable benefit from the public folder itself.